# Re-direct dynamic URLs from express to react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, webpack, react-router-redux

I have a react app, which uses a router and works fine if the URL is not entered directly into the address bar, but rather is set by react router when navigating the app. I have added ExpressJS to the app, by running the react app via the Express proxy. The goal is to re-direct any dynamic requests to the react app, so that it can handle it, instead of Express. I have looked at many examples and tried using them, but I had no luck in making the re-direct work.

The folder structure and key file locations are as follows:

> [Root directory]
>   ---- [client]
>   --------- [node_modules]
>   --------- [public]
>   --------- [scss]
>   --------- [src]
>   --------- package.json
>   --------- webpack.config.js
>   ---- [server]
>   --------- index.js
>   ---- [node_modules]
>   ---- package.json

The "client" directory contains the react app. The "server" directory contains the Express app. The Express app's package.json is in the root directory, while react app's package.json is in the "client" directory.

***server/index.js***

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const app = express();

// Serve static files
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client/public')));

app.get('*', function(request, response) {
response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client/public', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(PORT, function () {
console.error(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

***client/package.json***

Contains `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"`

***client/webpack.config.js***

Contains the following for devServer, entry, and output (I excluded various loaders as irrelevant for URL processing):

```
const BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'build');
const SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');

module.exports = (env = {}) => {
  return {
    entry: {
      index: [SRC_DIR + '/index.js']
    },
    output: {
      path: BUILD_DIR,
      filename: '[name].bundle.js'
    },
    devtool: env.prod ? 'source-map' : 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    devServer: {
      contentBase: BUILD_DIR,
      compress: true,
      hot: true,
      open: true,
      historyApiFallback: true
    }
  }
};
```

***client/src/index.js***

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import { Route } from 'react-router';

import { ConnectedRouter, routerReducer, routerMiddleware, push } from 'react-router-redux';

import rootReducer from './reducers';


// Wrapper
import SiteWrapper from './wrappers/SiteWrapper/'

// Pages
import Error404 from './ErrorPages/Error404/'

const history = createHistory();

const middleware = routerMiddleware(history);

const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    rootReducer,
    router: routerReducer
  }),
  applyMiddleware(middleware)
)

ReactDOM.render((
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <div>
        <Route exact path="/404" name="Error 404" component={Error404}/>
        <Route path="/" name="Home" component={SiteWrapper}/>
      </div>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

I first run the Express app, which starts listening on port 5000, and then I run the react app. When entering a dynamic URL `http://localhost:7500/dynamicurl/test-dynamic-url`, the app no longer shows 404, but then it doesn't show anything at all, and this is what I see in the developer console:

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:7500/dynamicurl/index.fonts.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
test-dynamic-url:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:7500/dynamicurl/index.styles.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
test-dynamic-url:54 GET http://localhost:7500/dynamicurl/index.bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED
```

What am I doing wrong here? Did I miss something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: problem is related to resolving file paths. as you can see on the error `GET http://localhost:7500/dynamicurl/index.bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED` this hints that index.blundle.js is not accessible. your index.html should properly find the root and apply its requires there eg. `<script src="theRoot/index.bundle.js" />` if this is done by webpack find a suitable plugin

Comment: Thanks Rei. I understand that it cannot find those files, because they were never generated since I am in development mode right now. Does this mean that in order to re-direct dynamic URLs to react I need to build the bundle after every change in react app's source? Also, it is pointing to dynamicurl/index.bundle.js, where dynamicurl is not even a physical directory